# How to fetch data based on date using criteria query?

Tags: java, criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I'm working with criteria query and want to fetch data based on date. However, criteria query like condition does not work with date.

i get date like `2020-08-25` from user.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<FermBatch> cq = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<MyClass> root = cq.from(MyClass.class);
cq.where(cb.like(root.get(MyClass_.date), date+"%"));
return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

With this like condition, it shows error:

> The method like(Expression, String) in the type
> CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path,
> String)

And in my db date is stored in like this `2020-08-25 03:02:06`
How can I get all data based on passed date (only using date, time does not matter).

I also tried this solution from other stackoverflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153144/how-to-search-date-field-for-a-string-using-jpa-criteria-api):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> cq = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<MyClass> entity = cq.from(MyClass.class);
cq.select(entity);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(entity.get(MyClass_.date).as(String.class)), "%"+date.toLowerCase()+"%")); 

Path<Tuple> tuple = entity.<Tuple>get("date");
if(tuple.getJavaType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)){
    Expression<String> dateStringExpr = cb.function("DATE_FORMAT", String.class, entity.get("date"), cb.literal("'%d/%m/%Y %r'"));
    predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(dateStringExpr), "%"+date.toLowerCase()+"%"));
}

cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
TypedQuery<MyClass> query = em.createQuery(cq); 
return query.getResultList();
```

This returned an empty arraylist. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your `MyClass` entity ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date comparison using the JPA criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424516/date-comparison-using-the-jpa-criteria-api)

Comment: @Rono thank you for reply. i posted answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to pass the "data" as milliseconds; it's always easier.

Anyway you should not use the operator "like" on a DATE; you should use equals, lower, or greather than.

```
long millis = 1598359174854l; // Tue Aug 25 2020 12:39:34
Predicate pred = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    root.get(MyClass_.date),
                    new Date(millis);
```

If you have the String, you should first convert the string to DATE, and then you have to compare:

```
String date = "2020-08-25";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date cal = dateFormat.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> query = builder.createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<MyClass> root = query.from(MyClass.class);
    
    Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
    predicate = builder.like(root.get(MyClass_.date).as(String.class), "%"+date+"%"); 
    
    query.where(predicate).select(root);;
    
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Thank you all.